# Calculation of the convolution of Cauchy density function $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ab}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{y^2+a^2}\frac{1}{(x-y)^2+b^2}dy$

Tags: calculus, probability, convolution

I tried to calculate the following integral, which is the convolution of Cauchy density function:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ab}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{y^2+a^2}\frac{1}{(x-y)^2+b^2}dy$$

I tried to use substitution, let $x-y=t$, then $y=x-t$

So  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ab}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{(x-t)^2+a^2}\frac{1}{t^2+b^2}dt$$

But it is still hard to solve.

Could someone kindly provide some help? Thanks!

Comment: Try partial fractions

Comment: @MJay1985 Thanks! I will try that.

Comment: Any restrictions on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The convolution of two Cauchy density functions is the density of the sum of two independent Cauchy random variables enjoying the respective densities. It might be easier to use _characteristic_ functions (or Fourier transforms) to deduce the answer: the characteristic function
of a Cauchy random variable is of the form $\alpha e^{-\beta\cdot|\omega|}$. and so the product of two such functions is of the same form.  Of course, if you are _required_ to use the convolution formula, this will not work.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks! I am required to calculate that directly without using transforms. So I am trying the partial fractions.

Comment: Note that you have an extra negative sign after the change of variables. This is because making the change alters the _limits_ to $(\infty, -\infty)$ from the original $(-\infty,\infty)$. But, you are still using $(-\infty,\infty)$ and so have an extra negative sign.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are right. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This is a standard example: If $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \mathrm {i.i.d.} ~ \mathrm{Cauchy}$ with median $0$ and first and third quartiles $\pm1$ and $\bar X = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$, then $\bar X$ actually has the same distribution as $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.  What works when the variance is finite doesn't work here. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Maybe I'll come back and post something later, but for now I'll say this much: I'd start by thinking about partial fractions.  Your denominator is initially a product of two irreducible quadratic factors. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks! I am trying to understand things in this paper.  On the Convolution of Cauchy Distributions
by Dwass, Meyer
The American Mathematical Monthly, 01/1985, Volume 92, Issue 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming WLOG $a,b>0$, then using partial fraction decomposition and/or the residue theorem it follows that:

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{(y^2+a^2)((y-x)^2+b^2)} = \frac{\pi(a+b)}{ab\left(x^2+(a+b)^2\right)}.\tag{1}$$

That can be achieved also by convolving two [Laplace distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution), as pointed in the comments.

Comment: What do you have for the partial fractions?

Comment: Sorry, can you give some hint about how to use the partial fraction decomposition? I don't understand where the $y$ goes (or where the $\pi$ comes in).